# articulated bus

Tags: meaning, word-request

I want to describe the network of routes in my city and I want to talk about the buses that serve different routes. So there are two types of buses, the normal bus (with one wagon), and the one with two wagons:

> Every route has over 35 stops and served by normal or articulated bus.

Can I use this form `normal or articulated bus`?

Comment: If you're speaking to an American, probably no - I've never heard those expressions.

Comment: In Britain they are better known as a *bendy bus*.

Comment: @AlexK - In New York City, *articulated bus* is what we call them.  For example, [MTA NYC Transit Introduces New Articulated Bus into SBS service](http://www.mta.info/news/2013/03/14/mta-nyc-transit-introduces-new-articulated-bus-sbs-service-three-doors-%E2%80%93-less)  I think the term just isn't very common because these buses aren't very common either.

Comment: @TheBook - You would have to say *Every route has over 35 stops and **is** served...* because "served" is a past participle, which works like an adjective.

Answer (score 3):

**Articulated bus** has the specific meaning of a bus which is contiguous (you can walk from end to end), but bends in the middle (to get around corners).  In London, these buses are also referred to as **bendy buses**.

**A normal bus** would be referred to as just **a bus**, since the norm is that busses are not articulated.

Not to be confused with **an articulate bus** which would be a bus that is well-spoken, if it were to exist.

Comment: In London, all busses are well spoken. Except the cockney ones. They can be hard to understand.

Comment: Maybe because there's no rhyme for **bus**?  Cheers me old china!

Answer (score 2):

According to Wikipedia, the terms in use include "[rigid bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_bus)", "non-articulated bus", and "standard bus".

> The term "**rigid bus**" is not used in American English, where the distinction is commonly made using the term "**non-articulated" bus** or, when the context is clear, "**standard" bus**. However, the expression "standard bus" can be confusing, because it is sometimes used, in other English speaking countries, to refer to a uniform bus design developed for and by a number of European bus manufacturers, in two model generations, between the 1960s and the end of the 20th century. (Wikipedia, "[Rigid bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_bus)")

Make your choice.

Since your example sentence provides enough context for the reader to guess that a non-articulated bus is being contrasted with an articulated bus, I guess you could safely use **standard**.

If every route is served by one bus only:

> Every route has over 35 stops and is served either by a standard or an articulated bus.

If every route is served by several buses of one type:

> Every route has over 35 stops and is served by either standard or articulated buses.

If every route is served by several buses of different types:

> Every route has over 35 stops and is served by standard and articulated buses.